# Codeigniter Searchbar

Tags: php, codeigniter, search, construct

Searchbar is working in codeigniter website but it does not load suggestion products. As I want if someone write 'dell' in searchbay he should get dell laptops suggestions below. and one another thing 'enter' button does not work for search one have to click the search icon to search the product.code is below
Controller

```
function text_search(){
    if ($this->crud_model->get_settings_value('general_settings','vendor_system') !== 'ok') {
        $search = $this->input->post('query');
        $category = $this->input->post('category');
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/home/category/'.$category.'/0-0/0/0/'.$search, 'refresh');
    }else{
        $type = $this->input->post('type');
        $search = $this->input->post('query');
        $category = $this->input->post('category');
        if($type == 'vendor'){
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/home/store_locator/'.$search, 'refresh');
        } else if($type == 'product'){
            redirect(base_url() . 'index.php/home/category/'.$category.'/0-0/0/0/'.$search, 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
function get_type_name_by_id($type, $type_id = '', $field = 'name')
{
    if ($type_id != '') {
        $l = $this->db->get_where($type, array(
            $type . '_id' => $type_id
        ));
        $n = $l->num_rows();
        if ($n > 0) {
            return $l->row()->$field;
        }
    }
}
function get_settings_value($type, $type_name = '', $field = 'value')
{
    if ($type_name != '') {
        return $this->db->get_where($type, array('type' => $type_name))->row()->$field;
    }
}
```

View

```
<div class="header-search">
                <?php
                    echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php/home/text_search/', array(
                        'method' => 'post'
                    ));
                ?>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="query" placeholder="<?php echo translate('what_are_you_looking_for');?>?"/>
                    <select
                        class="selectpicker header-search-select cat_select hidden-xs" data-live-search="true" name="category"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo translate('select');?>">
                        <option value="0"><?php echo translate('all_categories');?></option>
                        <?php
                            $categories = $this->db->get('category')->result_array();
                            foreach ($categories as $row1) {
                                if($this->crud_model->if_publishable_category($row1['category_id'])){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row1['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row1['category_name']; ?></option>
                        <?php
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php
                        if ($this->crud_model->get_type_name_by_id('general_settings','58','value') == 'ok') {
                    ?>
                    <select
                        class="selectpicker header-search-select" data-live-search="true" name="type" onchange="header_search_set(this.value);"
                        data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo translate('select');?>">
                        <option value="product"><?php echo translate('product');?></option>
                        <option value="vendor"><?php echo translate('vendor');?></option>
                    </select>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    <button class="shrc_btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /Header search -->
```